# Enclosing main invocation of a function in an if

Tags: design-patterns, python

As a part of my school CS class, I am reading *Python Programming* by John Zelle.  In the book, Zelle talks about surrounding the invocation of a main method with

```
if <condition>:
    main()
```

where the condition is something like `__name__ == '__main__'`.  My computer science teacher said that the necessity of this loop **depends** on if the program is importable and run-directly.  I know that because there are 2 variables, there can only be four combinations of importable and    run-directly.

I know from the book and my CS teacher that

> If a program is importable and is run directly, then main must be conditional.

However, I do not know the cases, which is what I am trying to figure out:

1. If `not importable and not run-directly`
2. If `importable and not run-directly`
3. If `not importable and run-directly`

**I think, but am not sure, that these are the correct answers.**

1. If `not importable and not run-directly`, then it must be in a conditional
2. If `importable and not run-directly`, then it doesn't have to be in a conditional.
3. If `not importable and run-directly`, then it doesn't have to be in a conditional.

> "Are the statements above correct?" is what I am trying to figure out.

I have tried finding this information in the book, but is unfortunately unavailable.

Comment: This is a well written and researched homework question. A welcome surprise, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close, but are missing one aspect.

If a program is importable and is run directly, then main must be conditional.

If not importable and not run-directly, then main is irrelevant. Actually, the entire contents of the file are irrelevant.

If importable and not run-directly, then main should not exist.

If not importable and run-directly, then main does not have to be in a conditional. It's still a good idea, as it'll help avoid accidentally omitting it were needed, and it causes no harm.